# Looking for tips on managing complexity with SCM repositories

Tags: svn

I am a solo developer in my department and I have a lot of individual projects, all created and managed by me. I started using SVN at ProjectLocker via Versions on the Mac a couple years ago when the variety of projects started getting unwieldy.

*Scenario 1*:
Now I have a process that is of reasonable complexity it can be broken up into multiple smaller applications and they all share files. In one phase, there is a single shared file—a constants file—that is shared between a Cocoa app and an iPhone app framework. In the second phase, the iPhone app framework will be used to create individual apps of the same ilk—controller classes and what not will all be the same—but with different content in each.

The problem that I am running across is that the file in the first phase is in one repository with the application that started it, and the app framework is in a second, separate repository.

*Scenario 2*:
I have another application framework that partially relies on code from an open source project. This is all internal, non-commerical work, but again, the application framework is going to be used to create a variety of unique products and processes.

So, now I have an internally managed repository and an externally managed one out of my control. I make little changes to the open source code to meet the needs of my framework when there is an update I download, but I never commit back into the external repository (though, now that I think about it, I don't think I'm committing it to mine either. Oops).

**The Problem**
I have all of this set up on my production Mac quite nicely, but duplicating and subsequently maintaining that environment on my laptop has been challenging. For Scenario 1, I've thought of merging these two projects together into the same repository because they are, for all intents and purposes inextricably linked. But, Scenario 2, I think I'm stuck just managing files as best I can.

**The Question**
I'm wondering if anyone has any tips on how to manage either of these situations, as well as other complex SCM scenarios when it comes to linking various files from various repositories together. My familiarity with SVN only comes from my work with Versions. It's been great, but I'm a little out of my depth here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, you should look at SVN subrepositories using an externals definition. You put the share code in its own repo, while the projects sharing the code each include an externals reference to the subrepo. If you commit updates to the shared code, you can also update the subrepo reference to refer to the new revision.

For the second problem, you could either use subrepos again (assuming the external project is also under SVN), or you could use the vendor branch model.

Both of these are well described in the on-line [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) (externals definitions in chapter 3, and vendor branches in chapter 4).